# Is there an easy way to replace Azure Cloud Service reference dll without re-publishing the service?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have an Azure Worker Role running in a Cloud Service.  The worker is a wrapper around my custom library which runs code.  When I make a change to my library **I'd like to simple replace the old with the new**.  Currently I have to republish the entire Cloud Service project which takes time and seems like a wasted effort.  I understand it might be necessary when I have multiple instances or other issues, but for now I'd like to simply copy my new dll to the service instead of publishing the entire project.

Is this possible?

Comment: How do you deploy a new version?

Comment: I just right click and publish the Azure Cloud Service project.

Comment: Have you considered using a WebJob (the Web Apps equivalent to Worker Roles) instead? Deployments are easier and faster than with Cloud Services.

Comment: We are not going to use HTTP but rather TCP.  My understanding is web apps require http?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the documentation linked to by Ralf I found this:

> If your app’s backend infrastructure is stable, but the web roles need
>   more frequent updating, you can use Web Deploy to update **only a web
>   role in your project**. This is handy when you don’t want to rebuild and
>   redeploy the backend worker roles, or if you have multiple web roles
>   and you want to update only one of the web roles.

later it restates :

> Only web roles can be updated: Worker roles can’t be updated. In
>   addition, you can’t update the RoleEntryPoint in web role.cs.

For anyone wanting to update a web role this nugget is very important to remember:

> The changes are made directly to the virtual machine where the web
>   role is running. If this virtual machine has to be recycled, the
>   changes are lost because the original package that you published is
>   used to recreate the virtual machine for the role. You must republish
>   your application to get the latest changes for the web role.

Answer (score 1):

When you are developing and testing an Azure application, you can use Web Deploy to publish changes incrementally for your web roles.

More info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683672.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For webrole Web deployment could incrementally add the new file. If you Want not to enable web deploy you need to have remote Access enabled for the role, then you can connect to the instance and replace the .dll file.

Depending on the role you'll need to find IIS folder (in case of Webrole) or access `"%ROLEROOT%\AppRoot"` (in case of Worker Role).

You could need to restart the IIS instance in web role scenario. For worker role you'll need to kill WaWorkerHost, it will be restarted automatically

Comment: So, to clarify, I can use web deployment even for a worker role?

Comment: Just found this in documentation.  Only web roles can be updated: Worker roles can’t be updated. In addition, you can’t update the RoleEntryPoint in web role.cs.